# enter data to structure

Tags: c, struct

This code is going to a loop when I enter the name and it does not come out. What is the problem?

```
# define M 3
struct clas
{
    char name[16];
    int key;
};


struct node
{
    int n; 
    struct node *p[M];  
    struct clas clsf[M-1] ;
};

main()
{
    int i;

    struct clas clsf;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        root = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
        printf("enter name \n");
        scanf("%s\n",root->clsf[i].name);
        printf("%s\n",root->clsf[i].name);
        printf("enter key\n");
        scanf("%d", &root->clsf[i].key);
        printf("%d",root->clsf[i].key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try giving us some code that actually compiles

Comment: your struct name is clasifier or clas?

Comment: ...and after doing that you should tell us what the problem is in more detail, because after fixing your code to compile it does not seem to have a problem - at least not an infinite loop problem.

Comment: it is not classifier it is cla

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the `homework` tag wasn't appropriate for your previous questions. Additionally, you didn't learn much from them.

Comment: @Tim: Considering [his history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/565292/pradeep), very little progress has been made unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

- `root` is undefined, and there's an instance of an undefined `struct classifier`: `clsf`.

  Replace `struct classifier clsf;` with `struct node *root;`
- remove the ending `\n` from `scanf` format:

  rpelace `scanf("%s\n",root->clsf[i].name);` with `scanf("%s",root->clsf[i].name);`

Answer (score 1):

Replace only `struct classifier clsf;` to `struct node *root;`
nothing more required